# How do I always show detailed error messages in Chrome 28?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome 28 changed the error page to remove details by default. How can I always show the details without clicking "More"?

[hidden error message](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/b91f90b1-30ad-4f62-8c13-2f169c2ade9a/aed38ee4ef81578235dbd52714a81e13/res/bf43b6e0-fa86-453f-84ee-03c00b0a67df/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832)